# How to remove rendered route using gmap3 plugin?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I use GMAP3 plugin to render driving direction.  And would like to add a clear button so it can be clear but I haven't been able to find the right syntax in GMAP3.  Here is the my js code, modified from the sample in gmap3.net.  I have markers plotted already and latlng are retreived from plotted markers instead of from clicks position on the map.

```
function removePath() {
    $(mapID).gmap3({
        action: 'clear',
        name: 'directionRenderer'
        // tag: 'path'  // works too with tag instead of name
});

function updatePath() {
$(mapID).gmap3({
    action: 'getRoute',
    options: {
            origin: m1.getPosition(),
            destination: m2.getPosition(),
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    callback: function (results) {
            if (!results) return;
            $(mapID).gmap3({ 
                action: 'setDirections', 
                directions:results,

            });
    }
});
};

function updateDirection(mm) { // Directions between m1 and m2
var mmID = $(mm).prop('id');
...
if (mmID == 'clearDirection') {
...
    removePath();
    return;
};
...
if (m1 && m2) { updatePath(); };    
};

function initmap() {
    $(mapID).gmap3(
        {
        action: 'init',
        options: defaultMapOptions
        },
    // add direction renderer to configure options (else, automatically created with default options)
        {   action: 'addDirectionsRenderer',
        preserveViewport: true,
        markerOptions: { visible: false },
        options: {draggable:true},
        tag: 'path'
        },
    // add a direction panel
        {   action: 'setDirectionsPanel',
        id: 'directions'
        }
    );
```

};

A  is in place in HTML documents as directions panel.  It has a a wrapper  which is hidden when the route is cleared by using jquery css property change.  The wrapper div's display property is changed back to 'block' whenever value is assigned to either m1 or m2.

```
<body> 
...
<div id="direction_container" class="shadowSE">
    ....
    <div id="directions"></div>
    ....
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its absolutely working fine.

```
$map.gmap3({ action: 'clear', name: 'directionRenderer' });
```

*Instructions-
If you later draw the route then you must write below code otherwise directions not display.

```
$map.gmap3({ action: 'addDirectionsRenderer', preserveViewport: true, 
markerOptions: { visible: false} }, 
{ action: 'setDirectionsPanel', id: 'directions' });
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(mapID).gmap3({action:"clear", name:"directionRenderer"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It removes the route and I can add route back with new selection of m1 and m2 afterwards, However, setDirections ceases to work after it is used.  If I don't clear, just select different m1 or m2, both route and direction work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer above didn't work for me. I'm unsure if it's version related, but the solution I'm using is more simple:

```
$(your-selector).gmap3({clear: {}});
```

Afterwards, you can draw a new route without reconnecting the directions rendered with the map.